# Wordpress visibility=>visible not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very simple code that is supposed to return an array with all visible products according to https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query
But all I get is an empty array.

```
$query = new WC_Product_Query( array('visibility' => 'visible') );
$products = $query->get_products();

print_r($products);
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: where is your code located?

Comment: www.arco.gr/test but you need to set hosts file with this configuration  -> 163.172.78.137 www.arco.gr

Comment: the page contains only the above code. nothing else.

Comment: ok. but where is file, which contain the code? how do you call it?

Comment: it's located in /httpdocs/wp-content/themes/twentytwelvechild/test.php. I have created a new wordpress page called test and selected test.php as its template.

Comment: your code will work as expected. several questions. are you sure you have visible products? what is your woocommerce version? are you sure you're calling right file?

Comment: Yes I am sure a have visible products because I see them in the frontend in the catalog. Version 3.3.3. Yes I am sure i call the right file because if i use another attribute it returns successfully the products. Thanx again!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. This may help.

```
// Get products that show in the catalog.
$args = array(
    'visibility' => 'visible',
);
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
print_r($products);
```

Comment: `Array ( ).` That's all I get. Does this work for you?

Comment: what version of woocommerce do you have?

Comment: woocommerce 3.2.0

Comment: do you have any products on your website that is visible ?